# How can we set width and height of a movie clip?

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I created an empty movie clip, where i loaded image from cliploader. I want the movie clip to have fixed height and width, and the image should fit in the movie clip.

I could not figure out any method to do that. Can anyone help?

Note: I am using Actionscript 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's assume your movieclip that has loaded the image is called pic_holder 
you set it's width and height via pic_holder._width pic_holder._height properties

but i guess you have already tried this and your problem is that it doesn't work. the problem, most likely is that you are trying to resize it before the image has loaded. therefore you must resize the image *after* it's loaded.

therefore you may
a) either loop continuously and check to see if it's loaded or not
b) add an event listener that will call the resizing function when the picture is loaded

a)

```
this.pic_holder.onEnterFrame = function(){
  if(this._width>0){
    this._width=...your width...
    this._height=...your height...
    this.onEnterFrame=null;
  }
}
```

b) extracted from [as2 language reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001383.html). note that we are using loadClip instead of loadMovie

```
  var loadListener:Object = new Object();
  loadListener.onLoadComplete = function(target_mc:MovieClip, httpStatus:Number):Void {
    target_mc._width=...your width...
    target_mc._height=...your height...
  }
  var mcLoader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
  mcLoader.addListener(loadListener);
  mcLoader.loadClip("..path to image..", pic_holder);
```

Comment: it resizes the image, but still the height of different images are different and it overflows

Comment: which version did you use? i'm not sure what you're asking though. what do you mean the heights are different? the height will be exactly the number you set

Comment: adobe flash cs6, flash player 11.2.202.228... , actionscript 2.0

Comment: i mean which version of the two provided codes. and you still did not clarify what do you mean, the code sets the height to the number you set

Comment: i loaded image using an xml file, created an empty movie clip, loaded the clip, and then resized the image using ur technique. The stage is 476x290 When i debug it, setting height n width=10, different image i load has different heights.

Comment: i asked: which version of my "technique" did you use? i have provided two answers. have you tried the other technique? i have tried both of them right now and they don't seem to be setting heights differently. do you mean unproportional scaling or something?

Comment: i used version b. And the multiple image i load has visibly different heights/widths.

Comment: so the images you load have different heights/widths. how is this related to the question? what are you trying to achieve? set their width/height as a multiplicative of the original? scale them down proportionally to the same width? scale them down proportionally to the same height? you need to explain what are you trying to do